# Find a ring homomorphism $\tau: \mathbb{F} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-fields, finite-rings

Just working on some exam prep questions, and I'm a bit stuck on this one.

> Let $ \mathbb{F} = \{ a + bX + cX^2 | a,b,c \in \mathbb{F}_2 = \{0,1\} \} $ be a ring with the operations:
>
> Addition, defined as:
>
> $(a + bX + cX^2) + (a' + b'X + c'X^2) = (a+a')+(b+b')X + (c+c')X^2 $
>
> and multiplication by formally multiplying out the expressions and
>   setting $X^3 = 1+X$
>
> Given that $ \psi : \mathbb{F} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}  $ is an
>   isomorphism:
>
> Where $ \psi(a + bX + cX^2) = (a + bX + cX^2)^2  $
>
> Find the formula for a ring homorphism $\tau: \mathbb{F} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$, where ${\tau}^2=\psi$

Since:

$$ \psi (a + bX + cX^2) = (a + bX + cX^2)^2 $$

$$ = (a + bX + cX^2)(a + bX + cX^2)  = a + cX + (b+c)X^2 $$ (using that $a + a = 0$ and $a^2 = a$ for $ \forall a \in \mathbb{F}$)

I know I require a $\tau$, such that

$$\tau^2 = \tau \circ \tau =  a + cX + (b+c)X^2 $$

However, I am really not sure where to start beyond guessing. I know it is not simply the identity map.

Since we are working over the field $\mathbb{F}_2$, I tried $ \tau = \psi^2 $ So that $ \tau^2 = {\psi^2}^2 = a + (b+c)X + bX^2 $. No Luck.

I'm certain this is not an exercise in guessing - but how should I approach this question?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: How are the multiplication and addition defined in the ring $\mathbb{F}$?

Comment: ahh sorry, I'll edit.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb F_2[X]/(x^3)$?

Comment: @CensiLI - I am not sure exactly what you mean. The practice question defines $\mathbb{F}$ exactly as written.

Comment: @JackReacher It seems that $\mathbb F$ is defined to be a ring. I just want to make sure what exactly the multiplication structure is.

Comment: @CensiLI - Yes $\mathbb{F}$ is a ring. I accidently left out the definitions of the operations earlier - hopefully it is clearer now?

Comment: @JackReacher Sorry I've not found the definitions of multiplication yet... Is my understanding $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb F_2[X]/(x^3)$ right?

Comment: The structure $\Bbb{F}$ is, indeed, the field of 8 elements, as given in Censi Li's answer. This implies that $\psi^3=\psi\circ\psi\circ\psi$ is the identity mapping, and  consequently $\tau=\psi\circ\psi$ should work.

Comment: Ok. Something seems to have gone wrong in your calculation. You have that $\psi(1)=1$, $\psi(X)=X^2$, $\psi(X^2)=X^4=X^2+X$ all right. Therefore
$\psi^2(1)=\psi(1)=1$, $\psi^2(X)=\psi(X^2)=X^2+X$, $\psi^2(X^2)=\psi(X^2+X)=X$. So if you set $\tau=\psi^2$, then $\tau^2(1)=1$,
$$\tau^2(X)=\tau(X^2+X)=\tau(X^2)+\tau(X)=X+(X^2+X)=X^2,$$
and
$$\tau^2(X^2)=\tau(X)=X^2+X.$$ So $\tau^2$ agrees with $\psi$ on the basis elements, and hence as linear mappings they are equal.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks - that is a nice way to look at it, which i didn't see before.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - Sorry can I just ask. How do you conclude that since $\mathbb{F}$ is the field of 8 elements that $\psi^3$ is the identity mapping? I can directly calculate it - but how did you know?

Comment: You mean $\psi^3$? Well, you need Galois theory for that. It is well known that the Galois group is cyclic of order three, so it follows. It sounds like you have quite started on Galois theory yet, so it is no wonder that it isn't "obvious" to you. Instead, you can check that $\tau$ and $\psi$ are inverses of each other.

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks - yes Galois theory will be discussed in the 2nd half of my current course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X^3-X- 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb F_2[X]$, $\mathbb F\simeq \mathbb F_2[X]/(X^3-X-1)\simeq\mathbb F_8$. The only isomorphism over $F_8$ are identity, $a\mapsto a^2$ and $a\mapsto a^4$. In your problem $\psi$ is $a\mapsto a^2$ and $\tau: a\mapsto a^4$ satiesfies $\tau^2=\psi$.

Comment: Yes, thanks very much - I realised that I made some calculation errors - it indeed works.